# Non-abelian Berry connection : clashing time-ordering conventions, and component-wise form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge-theory, topological-insulators, berry-pancharatnam-phase, anyons

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $k$-dimensional parameter space associated to a quantum system with an $N$-dimensional ground state. As usual, we assume the system is subject to some adiabatic tuning of parameters described by a loop $C\subset \mathcal{M}$ given by $\lambda:[0,T]\to\mathcal{M}$.  This tuning rotates the Hilbert space of the system (it is unitarily transformed), meaning the Hamiltonian at time $t$ is given by

$H(\lambda(t))=uH_{0}u^{\dagger} \ \ , \ \  u=u(\lambda(t))$

where $u\in U(N)$ and $u(0)=u(T)=id$. Let $\mathcal{H}(\lambda)$ be the Hilbert space at time $t$, and let $\Pi(\lambda)$ be the projector onto the ground state of $\mathcal{H}(\lambda)$.  The components ($\mu=1,\dots,k)$ of the Berry connection $\mathbf{A}$ are then claimed (in Section 2.2.2 of Jiannis Pachos' book [1](https://theory.leeds.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/55/2017/06/IntroTQC.pdf)) to be given by

$A_{\mu}=\Pi(\lambda) \left[u^{\dagger}\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda^{\mu}} u\right]\Pi(\lambda)$

**Time-ordering trouble: left to right vs. right to left.**

Let's split up the interval $[0,T]$ into $N$ equal segments. As per equation (2.27) of [1](https://theory.leeds.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/55/2017/06/IntroTQC.pdf), the time-evolution operator $\mathcal{U}(0,T)$ is given by

$\mathbf{T}\lim_{N\to\infty}\Pi_{i=1}^{N}u_{i}\exp(-iH_{0}\Delta t)u_{i}^{\dagger}$

where $u_{i}:=u(\lambda(t_{i}))$ at time $t=t_{i}$, with $t_{i}$ lying in the $i^{th}$ time interval. So far so good. Then we get to equation (2.28) of [1](https://theory.leeds.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/55/2017/06/IntroTQC.pdf), which expands the time-ordered product to get pairs of unitaries $u^{\dagger}_{i}u_{i+1}$. Is this a blunder (??) -- time-ordering should have time *increasing* from right to left? The same (seemingly reverse) time-ordering appears in the accepted answer to the [physics.SE question [2]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/370596/why-is-berry-connection-a-connection).

> **Q1.** Surely we should have $u^{\dagger}_{i+1}u_{i}$? I.e. shouldn't the connection actually be given by $A_{\mu}=\Pi(\lambda) \left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda^{\mu}} u^{\dagger}\right)u\right]\Pi(\lambda)$ ?

**Vindication (?!) [Wilczek & Zee]**

In the original paper by Wilczek & Zee [4] (cited by Pachos in his book), it seems that the 'correct' form of the connection I propose in **Q1** agrees (*up to complex conjugation...*) with the equation (7) of their paper. Furthermore, the connection gauge-transforms as I'd expect (see equation (10) of their paper), which is different to equation (2.36) of Pachos.

**Deducing components of the Berry connection**

In equation (1.52) of the notes by Tong [3](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe/qhe.pdf), the components of the Berry connection are given by

$[A_{\mu}]_{ba}=-i\langle n_a|\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda^{\mu}}n_b \rangle$

where $\{|n_{i}(\lambda)\rangle\}_{i=1}^{N}$ is an orthonormal basis for the ground state space of $\mathcal{H}(\lambda)$.

> **Q2.** How do we get to the component-wise form of the Berry connection $A_{\mu}$ *from the matrix form given above?* I've tried and have had no luck.

**References**

(1) Pachos, J. (2012). [Introduction to Topological Quantum Computation](https://theory.leeds.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/55/2017/06/IntroTQC.pdf)

(2) [Why is Berry connection a connection?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/370596/why-is-berry-connection-a-connection)

(3) Tong, D. (2016). "[The Quantum Hall Effect](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe/qhe.pdf)".

(4) Wilczek, F. and Zee, A. (1984). "Appearance of Gauge Structure in Simple Dynamical Systems", Physical Review Letters, 52(24). **N.B.** *you can find the paper on Sci-Hub, if struggling otherwise.*